# Java Script validation

Tags: php, javascript

Am validating a form for empty check.

All fields works fine.

I have a dropdown when i select some value from dropdown some fields will be disabled. onchanging the dropdown value someother fields will be disabled.

Now am struck in validating the fields which are getting disabled and enabled.

```
if((document.form1.varAuctionTime.disabled = false) && (document.form1.varAuctionTime.value == ""))
```

I used above code but it is enabling the fields.

can anybody help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upvoted Quentin's answer.

`document.form1.varAuctionTime.disabled = false` uses the assignment operator, which sets the value of `disabled` to `false`

`document.form1.varAuctionTime.disabled == false` will do a comparison and will return `true` if the value of disabled is `false` (or technically, if the value is `0` or an empty string)

`document.form1.varAuctionTime.disabled === false` will only return true if the value is `false` and not if it is `0` or an empty string. This is probably not required as AFAIK the `disabled` property will always return a boolean.

To give you a few alternatives that you may prefer; since the comparison operators return booleans, and the `disabled` property is a boolean anyway, you could just do the following

```
if(!document.form1.varAuctionTime.disabled && !document.form1.varAuctionTime.value)
```

Answer (score 6):

You are using `=` (assignment) where you want `==` (comparison)

Comment: OMG i did't checked it out. thank you i was struggling for half an hour.

Answer (score 0):

replace

document.form1.varAuctionTime.disabled = false

with

document.form1.varAuctionTime.disabled == false